# Stop Chrome Tab Sleeping/Hibernating

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs, page-refresh

How can I stop Chrome from having its tabs Sleep/Hibernate?  I'm running the "revolver" extension and I want the tabs to reload before I cycles to it.. however it seems that chrome's tabs are put in a state of hibernation so it doesn't reload until the tab is "active" and showing.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: [Stop Chrome from reloading tabs](//superuser.com/q/970244)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From wOxxOm's link:

"you can turn this off by going to "chrome://flags/" and selecting "Disabled" under "Enable tab discarding"

Comment: I believe this is renamed to 'Proactive Tab Freeze and Discard' and '#proactive-tab-freeze-and-discard'

Comment: 'Proactive Tab Freeze and Discard' and 'Enable tab discarding' both not found? @TankorSmash

Comment: Check `chrome://discards/`

Comment: any way to change it using chrome api? (like from chrome extension)

Answer (score 11):

See @joseantgv comment above

> Check chrome://discards/

Seems to be how chrome does this on latest build - Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: The column to change the check mark to a cross mark for is now called "Auto discardable". Search for the URL you want to change this for in column "Tab URL", then click on the "Toggle" link below the check mark (✔) to change it into a cross mark (✘️) and you are set.