# Stop Chrome Tab Sleeping/Hibernating 2020

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

How can I stop Chrome from having its tabs Sleep/Hibernate? I'm using an online timer and I really can't have it reset

This question was [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072206/stop-chrome-tab-sleeping-hibernating) in 2017 but the solution does not work anymore.

Comment: did any of the solutions work for you?

Comment: I'm surprised the timeout is only 10 minutes.  No other browser is that short.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

On Chrome version 83:

- Go to `chrome://discards/` (open as a URL).
- Find the tab of interest.
- Look at the "Auto Discardable" column, click "Toggle" to disable it.

Note that if the computer is low on RAM, keeping tab active may hurt performance and even halt the system. So make sure to close unnecessary tabs and extensions by yourself.

Comment: Is there a nuke solution to stop this behavior entirely for all tabs, not having to pre-define or single select tabs and/or URLs?

Comment: @JoelKarunungan None that I know of. Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: If you want to do it programmatically this should do it `chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {autoDiscardable: false});` This extension does that for all tabs in your browser: https://github.com/WorldLanguages/DoNotDiscard

Comment: @depsypher: That is interesting. The good point is that they may update the extension code when Chrome updates its API.

Comment: @depsypher I found the extension in chrome web store https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-automatic-tab-dis/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok?hl=en

Answer (score 11):

In newer Chrome versions (like version 109+) it's now visible in the settings:

```
Settings -> Performance -> Memory saver
```

[image]

Alternatively you can set exclusion rules (`Always keep theses sites active`) if you don't want to disable it completely.

Comment: +1 Also, the performance setting appears to be hidden in some cases.   You might have to force it be visible by setting `chrome://flags/#high-efficiency-mode-available` to enabled.

Comment: I have Memory Saver to off but it still hibernates my tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The [Disable automatic tab discarding](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-automatic-tab-dis/dnhngfnfolbmhgealdpolmhimnoliiok?hl=en) chrome extension does it automatically for all tabs. No need to pick and choose which tab.